# Encoding data in URL for efficient transport

Tags: java, performance, url, encoding, tracking

I'm searching for a library that can encode data in URL, because using plain "&param=value is" inefficient.

I'm looking for a library that will accept a defined set of parameters and will encode it into a format that is safe to sent over HTTP GET request. I will be using this to send tracking events from my player to the backend.

I remember reading at some blog post that Chrome is using a nice library to encode data when it send statistics back to google servers, that library was recently open sourced by Google. Alas, I can't find it, and I don't remember it's name :)

Thanks for helping,
Maxim.

Comment: Note that in practice URL length shouldn't exceed 2KB. May be browser/server dependent, but it is better to stay on the safe side.

Comment: You say "safe", but what do you mean?  Are you talking cryptography?

Comment: @jowie, I mean that too long URLs may simply get refused or truncated by some servers.

Comment: I thought the truncation happened at the browser side, especially older IE versions. But Péter Török's comment is indeed a good idea.

Comment: @Péter Török - sorry, my comment meant "safe" in the original post, not your comment.  The original post doesn't say what they mean by safe.

Comment: @MSalters, could be indeed - I had such a case many years ago and I can't recall the exact details anymore. Yes, it was IE :-)

Comment: @jowierun "safe" in terms legal values for HTTP request. IE. does not contain special characters such as / & ? that can cause transmission problems between the client and the server. Sorry for potentiality misleading - I did not meant "data security" safe.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean URL encoding? Then you can use `java.net.URLEncoder#encode(String,String)` for URL encoding a String with a given encoding (like "UTF-8").

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> using plain "&param=value is" inefficient.

?

It seems to me that any library that you use will, under the covers, be simply using string manipulation to build the URL, so Im struggling to see why you think using such a library will be more efficient.

What measurements have you taken to test your hypothesis? What performance levels do you need?

Comment: I mean that the "param" can be skipped as I know what value positions. Helios answer outlines the basics.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick and dirty solution I can propose this:

If:

- your set of params is fixed (or you can indicate the set of params using some short id)

Do:

1. **Remove the param name overhead** concatenate all in a String, byte[] or similar in a way you can decode it later :) I should avoid Java Serialization because it includes a lot of info. I'd try something simple like DataOutputStream.write*Type*. Simple to write and simple to read.
2. **Remove data redundancy** Zip it. Use `java.util.zip.GZipOutputStream`. That's why I prefer the step 1 to generate a byte[] representation!
3. Make it **URL-friendly**. Here you'll increase the size in bytes you need. So try to do it with the least overhead. I should try with Base64. It's zipped so it's not redundant (it uses the least space posible). So the only chance is to use a representation that don't use too much space. Hexa would double the size. But Base64 only adds 33%.

Theese steps are not complicated.

1. Uses a custom class. Maybe the [alternative serialization method](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) so it's easier to invoke.
2. Uses java.util.zip.GZipOutput/InputStream. It's straight-forward.
3. Uses some Base64 encoding/decoding library. Straigh-forward too.

Hope it helps!

Comment: One slight problem with Base-64 is its use of `/`. There are similar, more URL-friendly schemes.

Comment: Hi helios, what you describe is straight what I need, obviously I can implement that myself but the lib I'm talking about (that google released) already does all that. Regarding Base64. There is a version of Base64 that is url safe, for ex. see this implementation http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafe(byte[])